# New item for Layout activity

Tags: android

i need your help with understanding this isue :
i added new button item, this item is invisible when the application is running.
it means i can see just the "tvPeriod" TextView and the editText, i cant see the other objects.

thanks for help.

my layout code is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPeriod"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="enter your period day:" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etPeriodDntWant"
            android:layout_width="58dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnOk"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:text="@string/ok" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvResult"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="114dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post you're activity class because you're xml is perfect.

Comment: This XML should display four visible views: TextView, EditText, Button and another TextView. Do you have enough screen width?